# Safari font rendering poorly against background image

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNwrvZ?editors=1100) - Only a problem on Safari

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>

<div class="text">
  This is some sample text that doesn't look great.
</div>

<div class="text text-background">
  This is some sample text that looks stellar!
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ks.test/beaver_creek.jpg");
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}

.text-background {
  background-color: #464646;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I've found lots of related posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413969/lato-font-rendering-odd-in-safari-not-in-chrome-or-firefox) for example), but none that directly address the issue when a background image appears to be the culprit.

Only in Safari, I'm running into an issue where font renders poorly against a background image, but when I remove the background image and set it to gray the font looks fine.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: using css, put the image or both with the text on the hardware layer and see if any different -- (-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); transform: translateZ(0);) that usually gets rid of the blur -- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it didn't seem to have any effect.  Here's a pen demonstrating the issue.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNwrvZ?editors=1100